# Где найти APK-файл приложения StackExchange?

Tags: поддержка, мобильное-приложение

Официальное приложение [StackExchange](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) было удалено из PlayStore. В связи с чем возник вопрос: имеется ли у официальных лиц APK-файл приложения? Согласитесь, что скачивать его с просторов интернета было бы, как минимум, легкомысленно. Может имеется какое-либо другое проверенное приложение?

Comment: Так зачем его скачивать, если оно не поддерживается?

Comment: @АндрейNOP не поддерживается - это ещё не значит, что оно не работоспособно. Я периодически пользуюсь, правда с какого-то обновления Android приложение часто стало вылетать при открытии входящих сообщений.

Comment: Если есть телефон с уже установленым приложением, то можно поставить приложение, сохраняющее апк в пользовательскую папку (например, apk extractor) и сохранить себе на будущее. Если такого телефона нет, то у меня есть, выложу позднее куда-нибудь.

Comment: Можно достать из телефона, на который оно установлено.

Comment: @Qwertiy пробовал несколько способов с приложениями, которые должны его "извлекать", но ни один не сработал. Буду благодарен за дополнительную информацию по этой теме.

Comment: У меня телефон Realme - там через настройки можно встроенными средствами. А после обновления обещают вообще в меню ярлыков на рабочем столе добавить. Ну и учти, что всякие чистильщики системы могут их удалять.

Comment: @XelaNimed только что испробовал Apk Extractor и все сработало.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, Вы правы. Сейчас тоже попробовал Apk Extractor и всё получилось :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Благодаря [Эникейщику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282277) и [Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988) приложение было извлечено со смартфона Android приложением [Apk Extractor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ext.ui). APK-файл установился на Android 5.0.2, хотя извлекался с Android версии 9.0.
Принимая во внимание, что приложения со временем могут удаляться из магазина приложений публикую здесь [ссылку на извлечённый APK-файл](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8z7i2vz2usgkr28/Stack_Exchange.apk?dl=0).

Comment: В двенадцатом андроиде уже не работает ☹️

Answer (score 5):

Официально — это маловероятно.

Основания так считать:

1. [Can I download the Stack Exchange Android app for CyanogenMod without Google apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217762/383809)

   от 2014 года. В этом довольно старом обсуждении имеется ответ, что распространение APK на прямую поддерживаться не будет, а также приводится ряд аргументов.
2. [Оставленный без ответа вопрос о прямой ссылке на APK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222275/383809) от 2014 года.
3. (**и главное**) Официальный ответ на вопрос [Why did the Stack Exchange Android app disappear from the Play Store?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363043/383809)
   :

> Lastly, we will continue to maintain the mobile API routes that are still running server side as we have been doing because the maintenance is low and it’ll keep the app running for those who have already installed it. It should be noted however that services specific to the app will have low maintenance priority, components may be decommissioned as the need arises, and issues with the general network API will continue to have their normal maintenance priority.

то есть, API будет **пока** поддерживаться для тех, у кого приложение уже установлено. Однако, все будет медленно затухать. Вопрос как именно и что отвалится первым.

Исходя из вышеизложенного, моего личного опыта о жизненном цикле продукта, а также наблюдений за некоторыми стратегическими решениеями Stack Overflow, я практически не верю в то, что APK можно будет скачать с официальных или даже полуофициальных источников.

Однако, существует вероятность что для уже установленных из App Store'ов или скачанных (откуда бы то ни было) в будущем и установленных приложений — работа может сохраняться довольно долго. Ибо эти приложения уже давно не поддерживались, но, в принципе, работали.

Таким образом, скорее всего желающим придется довольствоваться любыми другими доступными способами скачать и установить APK, на свой страх и риск.